# Не удается подключиться к серверу Exchange 2016 через PowerShell из CentOS

Tags: centos, powershell, exchange

Необходимо подключиться к серверу Exchange 2016 через PowerShell из CentOS.
При подключении из Windows пользовался такой схемой:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://*******/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential (Get-Credential) 
Import-PSSession $Session
```

Из CentOS не получается. Перепробовал все возможные варианты аутентификации.
Подскажите, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: powershell-то тут абсолютно не по теме.